# Copyright logo & map visibility

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm aware of terms of using Google Maps API, but in the following case is a bit unclear:

I want to make the whole `mapView` container transparent by 50% or 60%. I don't want to modify or remove Google copyrights (Google logo in the corner).

Is it legal from this point of view? Does it violate Google's terms of use?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  Stack Overflow is about programming, not legal advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) explicitly forbids this kind of modification.

In **section 8.1.a**, Google defines "Brand features" as (emphasis mine):

> "Brand Features" means trade names, trademarks, **logos**, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.

According to this definition, the Google logo is a "Brand feature".

And later, in **section 8.4.b.viii** (emphasis mine):

> Restrictions. In using Google Brand Features, you will not:
>
> remove, distort, or alter any element of a Google Brand Feature (including squeezing, stretching, inverting, or **discoloring**).

So, making the map semi transparent and therefore the Google logo, can be considered *"discoloring a Google Brand Feature"* and would violate the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is allowed as per Google Maps terms and conditions stated on [Personalizing your map](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html):

> While we encourage annotations, **you must not significantly alter how
>   Google Maps, Google Earth or Street View would look online**. For
>   example, you're not allowed to make any changes to the colors of the
>   product interface or **alter how imagery appears** (such as adding clouds
>   or other natural elements, **blurring**, etc.).

That's my two cents :)

Answer (score -1):

You'll be fine with the transparency. I use the same effect myself. If they do notice and object, which is unlikely, they will warn you first, so you can remove the modification.